# Why Am I Unable To Connect To a WCF Service From SoapUI?

Tags: wcf, soapui

I created a sample WCFservice that provides four really simple services from 1 endpoint. Works fine within Visual Studio's (2010) WCF Test Client.

I was able to import the binding into SoapUI (4.5.2) and generate tests by referencing the wsdl.  However when i execute any test i get a timeout.

Keep in mind that the service is only running on localhost via visual studio. But i can access the wsdl so i think it should be able to execute the tests.  I keep getting timeouts and never hit service-side breakpoints.

Here's the endpoint i use in soapui

```
http://127.0.0.1:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfMathServLib/MathService/
```

Looks like WCF Test Client uses this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfMathServLib/MathService/mex
```

But neither really works for me. Any ideas?

Comment: the mex endpoint is not relevant, it is alternative to the WSDL not the runtime. most probably you use a WCF setting that soapUI does not support (the default WCF setting, WSHttpBinding, is not supported in its default config)

Comment: What can i use instead of wshttpbinding?

Comment: decide based on your needs. Basic http binding is a good option if you do not need security or are ok with transport security